# How to list "inproceedings" items with "volume X of ..." in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex with the authoryear style, which results for @inproceedings items in

> ... "Title". In: *Booktitle*. Vol. 123. Title of Series.

How can this be changed to:

> ... "Title". In: *Booktitle*, volume 123 of *Title of Series*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hack seems to do the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{filecontents} % Just for the example

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{volume}{Volume #1 of}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{series}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
    \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \setunit{\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Author2013,
    Title = {{A great paper}},
    Author = {A Author},
    Booktitle = {Booktitle},
    Series = {Title of Series},
    Volume = {1},
    Year = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{Author2013}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have just declared the field format for `volume` and `series`, and modified one line in the `inproceedings` driver to change the punctuation at the end of a unit.
In this simple example it works but I have not checked if it causes trouble when you have other fields, and there might be a better way of doing it.